# Nginx keeps showing Welcome to Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

I am using Cent OS 6.1.
I installed Nginx by ./configure method from source. I started the nginx server by `sudo nginx` and it can serve the Welcome to Nginx page.

However, when I edit the /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf file, I found that changing the `...location / {... }...` block has no effects.

For example, changing

```
location / {
    root html;
    index index.htm index.html;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    root xyz123; #which does not exist
    index index.htm index.html;
}
```

should give 404. But it keeps showing the welcome page.

Even I remove the whole location block, it still shows the welcome page. But if I change the `/usr/local/nginx/html` to `/usr/local/nginx/htmlxyz` it shows 404. Is there another conf file running that overridden the nginx.conf?

p.s. I did `sudo nginx -s stop` then `sudo nginx` or `sudo nginx -s reopen` but didnt help :(

Comment: I got it working with the yum installation. Building from rpm src from here http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/SRPMS/ works too. Just dunno why ...

Answer (score 0):

Why you install over EPEL. I've installed 10 nginx server just like that and it is working with Node.js.

Maybe you can get some error ? Show full ./configure.

Example Nginx / Php / Mysql for Centos :

https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.4

Default centos nginx html path :
/usr/share/nginx/html/